# XML - <xsl:for-each select="something/some" />

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am working on a school project and i am producing an xsl for an xml produced for me.
I am with a doubt, when i do `<xsl:for-each select="something/at/some">`there´s any change of getting back when i do `<xsl:value-of select="kapa/alright"/>`
because i want to use the value in `<me>` in the same cicle

Imagine an XML like

```
<something>
  <at>
    <some>
       <kapa>
          <alright>okay</alright>
       </kapa>
    </some>
  </at>
  <me>Hello</me>
</something>
```

What i want to do after is something like:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Me:</th>
        <th>you:</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="something/at/some">
        <tr>
          <th>
             <xsl:value-of select="kapa/alright"/>
          </th>
          <th>
             <xsl:value-of select="<!-- Here i would like to go back to get the value that is in <me> -->"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't describe your XSLT.  Include it.

Comment: that way i need to put all my code, and i tryed to explain

Comment: Having said that, note that your `xsl:for-each/@select` XPath doesn't exist in your XML because `some` is not a child of `something`.

Comment: already put ir right sorry

Comment: So, rather than going back and forth with us as you fix things that aren't in your real code, just post your real code.  Generally a [mcve] should be a part of your question.  Just be sure to prune it down the smallest example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: updated and i thing it's understandable now!

Comment: Your code and XML imply that there will only be a single `something` element.  Is this true?  And a single `something/me` element?

Comment: Yes, it´s true. I just want to know if i can use something like if i was getting back on folders. Ex: "../../../me"

Comment: If there's a single `me` element that you wish to select, use an absolute path: `/something/me`; otherwise, use a relative path: Within your loop over `some` elements, that would be `../../me`.

Answer (score 1):

As @zx485 suggests, you can navigate back up the tree using the parent or ancestor axis. Alternatively, you can bind a variable to the `me` element outside the xsl:for-each, and reference it inside:

```
    <xsl:variable name="ME" select="something/me"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="something/at/some">
        <tr>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="kapa/alright"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ME"/>
        </th>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation of your real code, you can use this template. It assumes that the template matches the root element and `something` is a child of it.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Me:</th>
        <th>you:</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="something/at/some">
        <tr>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="kapa/alright"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../me"/>
        </th>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Me:</th>
    <th>you:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>okay</th>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```